# Form if selected fields have no post value then dont sent email

Tags: php, forms, validation, isset

I have the following code which check if all variables are set, this will return true only if all arguments to isset()

```
if (isset($_POST['FirstName'], $_POST['Surname'], 
$_POST['Telephone'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['PickupPoint'],
$_POST['Destination'], $_POST['StartDate'], 
$_POST['NumberofPassengers'])) {

"if all fields have a POST value then send email"

else{
    echo "Please fill in all fields.";
}
```

However even when for example PickupPoint and Destination aren't filled in the email gets sent.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that a blank field still counts as being set. You will also need to check if it's empty using e.g. `$_POST['PickupPoint'] !== ''`

Full example:

`if (isset($_POST['FirstName'], $_POST['Surname'], 
$_POST['Telephone'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['PickupPoint'],
$_POST['Destination'], $_POST['StartDate'], 
$_POST['NumberofPassengers']) && $_POST['PickupPoint'] !== '' && $_POST['Destination'] !== '') { ...`

Though I'd recommend checking ALL fields